# What is different between getContext and getActivity from Fragment in support library?

Tags: android

What is different between `getContext()` and `getActivity()` from `Fragment` in support library?

Do they always return the same object? (activity associated with current fragment)

Comment: can you Call getContext() in fragment Directly? Rather you use getActivity().getContext()

Comment: yes, I can http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getContext()

Comment: started from android api 13

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In most cases there is no difference *but* ...

So originally `Fragments` were hosted in `FragmentsActivity` and back then to get `Context` one called `getActivity()`.

Just checked the sources and `Fragments` now can be hosted by anyone implementing [FragmentHostCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentHostCallback.html) interface.  And this changed in Support Library version 23, I think.

When using newer version of Support Library, when `Fragment` is not hosted by an `Activity` you can get different objects when calling `getActivity()` and `getContext()`.

When you call `getActivity()` you get an `Activity` which is a `Context` as well.
But when you call `getContext` you will get a `Context` which might not be an `Activity`.

Comment: Do you have examples of when a non-`Activity` class will/can implement `FragmentHostCallback`

Comment: @Sree What about nested fragments? I encountered this issue in a case where I was expected getActivity() but getActivity() is null. My case is a nested fragment, so maybe that's one of the cases of this?

Comment: @MattHorst NestedFragments are not Contexts. The context of the nested fragment is still the activity. I was wondering if there are any non-Activity classes that are also contexts

Comment: @Sree Alright, thanks. I understand the question, I guess I was just wrong about that being a possible cause. I was looking more last night at the support classes, it seems like it's pretty bare-bones right now. I wonder if there aren't any non-Activity classes yet that are contexts, but FragmentHostCallback has been created so they can move in that direction.

Comment: Never in my entire experience I had to work with `Fragment` which context is not `Activity`. And can't think of a case like this.

Answer (score 9):

So far, the only provided implementation of `FragmentHostCallback` (in the OS and the support library) always returns the same value for both `getContext()` and `getActivity()`.

However, the other constructors of `FragmentHostCallback` suggest that in future implementations, we may get:

- A null `Activity` and a non-null `Context` which is not an `Activity`. This looks improbable but we can imagine that fragments could be used outside Activities in the future, or be fully sandboxed.
- A non-null `Activity` and a non-null `Context` which is not the same instance as the `Activity`. For example, `Context` could be a [`ContextThemeWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html).

**Conclusion:** when you can, use `getContext()`. When you need Activity-specific calls, use `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 4):

Activity is a subclass of Context. Activity has also Window elements and access to UI methods, Context doesn't. However, in the majority of the cases, it's the same if you need only the Context.

Comment: Activity is a subclass of Context.

Comment: Activity is a subclass of Context*

Comment: but that same object with different interfaces, and if getActivity return null, getContext return null too. Is it true?

Comment: @ cyroxis & @ Alberto: yes sorry, thanks for the correction. Edited.

@mlevytskiy: it shouldn't return null, but if it does, yes because the object referred is exactly the same (the activity) but in one case it's only an upcast. Indeed in normal Fragments you don't even have getContext.

Comment: @JörnBuitink no, it's not true. with new Support Library `getContext()` and `getActivity()` can return different things, ie. one might be NULL and another not. It depends on `FragmentHostCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

**getContext():-** Returns the context the view is currently running in. Usually the currently active Activity. `getContext()` is not defined in an Activity. It's used in a View (or View subclass) to get a reference to the enclosing context (an Activity).

**getActivity():-** This method gives the context of the Activity. You can use it is like the `yourActivity.this`. getActivity() is normally used in fragments to get the context of the activity in which they are inserted or inflated.

Answer (score 1):

**[getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext())** - Returns the context view only current running activity.

**[getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29)**- Return the Activity this *fragment* is currently associated with.

`getActivity()` can be used in a Fragment for getting the parent ***Activity of the Fragment*** .

Answer (score -1):

[getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) :

> Returns the context view only current running activity.

[getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29):

> Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
     * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
     */
    public Context getContext() {
        return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
    }

    /**
     * Return the {@link FragmentActivity} this fragment is currently associated with.
     * May return {@code null} if the fragment is associated with a {@link Context}
     * instead.
     */
    final public FragmentActivity getActivity() {
        return mHost == null ? null : (FragmentActivity) mHost.getActivity();
    }
```

from source code, we can find that when a fragment is attached to an Activity, getContext returns null. While getActivity returns null when a fragment is attached to context instead

Comment: according to this code block, getContext will NOT return null if fragment is attached to an activity but getActivity WILL return null if fragment is attached to a context