# Context.getResources() NPE

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got several crash reports about our app.

This bug was filed from the Socorro interface and is
report bp-d1b4cdb8-fd3f-457b-9a29-df9192170112.
Socorro-Signature:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ''android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'' on a null object reference: at dnu.afterTextChanged(CommentOperatingFragment.java)`

Java stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
     at dnu.afterTextChanged(CommentOperatingFragment.java:252)
     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7929)
     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4084)
     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3933)
     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:85)
     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3908)
     at dnv.a(CommentOperatingFragment.java:269)
     at dpz.a(SoftKeyboardStateHelper.java:84)
     at dpz.onGlobalLayout(SoftKeyboardStateHelper.java:47)
     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:912)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1899)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5915)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:773)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:556)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:759)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Here is my code in CommentOperatingFragment:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        …...
        mCommentEdt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence,
                                          int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence,
                                      int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (mCommentEdt.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    mPostTxt.setClickable(false);
                    mPostTxt.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getContext().getResources(),// Line 252
                            R.color.article_comment_area_post_color_without_text, null));
                } else {
                    mPostTxt.setClickable(true);
                    mPostTxt.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getContext().getResources(),
                            R.color.article_comment_area_post_color_with_text, null));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

It happened on several devices.

6.0.1，SAMSUNG-SM-G935A
6.0.1, SAMSUNG-SM-G890A
6.0， Alco
6.0.1，motorola，XT1585

I don't know if it is the same with https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56296

I also wonder if it is related to the getContext location.  I called it in Fragment.onViewCreated.

But it says in the source code :The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.

Comment: Why not using `getActivity()` ?

Comment: you can also use view.getcontext()

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK

@keyur9779

Thanks for commenting. Could you guys point out the difference among `getActivity`, `getContext` and `view.getContext` in here?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ResourcesCompat.getColor(getContext().getResources(),
                            R.color.article_comment_area_post_color_with_text, null)
```

to

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.article_comment_area_post_color_with_text)
```

Comment: Could you explain why the former will throw an exception?

Comment: I've read before that sometimes `getContext()` will return NPE.
You should use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()` during development.

Comment: Did you remember where you read that? Or could you give me some materials about getContext() will return NPE? I never knew such thing will happen.

Comment: Because you put your code in Fragment so you can read this to understand why
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32227421/4316327

Comment: @FrancisBacon accept the answer it you done by it. Thanks.

Comment: I read this before, but there seems to be no evidence that `getContext` will return NPE.
It seems that it at least do not specify in which situation will return NPE.
CommentOperationFragment is in an Activity which extends AppCompatActivity and thus extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: I will surely accept the answer if it solves the issue. Thanks for your answer ahead. But until now it seems to me there is no evidence saying `getContext` will return NPE and `getActivity` will not.