# java.lang.ClassCastException: cast to created interface issue?

Tags: java, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am trying to add the option to click on the images/videos in my Gridview within a fragment but it says I cannot cast my main activity to OnClickThumbListener interface that I created...
I think it is because I am using fragment and not FragmentActivity.

Main:

```
public class MyPostsScreen extends Fragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, MediaStoreAdapter.OnClickThumbListener{

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private final static int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMMISSION_RESULT = 0;
    private final static int MEDIASTORE_LOADER_ID = 0;
    private RecyclerView mThumbnailRecyclerView;
    private MediaStoreAdapter mMediaStoreAdapter;

    public MyPostsScreen() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_posts_screen, container, false);

        mThumbnailRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailRv);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 3);
        mThumbnailRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mMediaStoreAdapter = new MediaStoreAdapter(this.getActivity());
        mThumbnailRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMediaStoreAdapter);

        checkReadExternalStoragePermission();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }
}
```

MediaStoreAdapter:

```
public class MediaStoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MediaStoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Cursor mMediaStoreCursor;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private OnClickThumbListener mOnClickThumbListener;

    public interface OnClickThumbListener {
        void OnClickImage(Uri imageUri);
        void OnClickVideo(Uri videoUri);
    }
    public MediaStoreAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        //TODO: Figure out why this fails Java Class Exception, and FIX.
        this.mOnClickThumbListener = (OnClickThumbListener)activity;
    }
}
```

ERROR:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: example.fadysi.fomoapptest2, PID: 21631
>                                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: example.fadysi.fomoapptest2.MainActivity
>   cannot be cast to
>   example.fadysi.fomoapptest2.ThumbnailVideoPlay.MediaStoreAdapter$OnClickThumbListener
>                                                                                    at
>   example.fadysi.fomoapptest2.ThumbnailVideoPlay.MediaStoreAdapter.(MediaStoreAdapter.java:31)
>                                                                                    at layout.MyPostsScreen.onCreateView(MyPostsScreen.java:65)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1643)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1272)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1646)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:703)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:768)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.refle

Comment: the interface is implemented by the fragment and not the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
private final Context mActivity;
....
....

public MediaStoreAdapter(Context context, OnClickThumbListener onClickThumbListener) {
    this.mActivity = context;
    this.mOnClickThumbListener = onClickThumbListener;

}
```

And in your `MyPostsScreen` fragment, call the adapter constructor like following,

```
mMediaStoreAdapter = new MediaStoreAdapter(this.getActivity(), this);
mThumbnailRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMediaStoreAdapter);
```

This is because your interface is implemented by the fragment, not the MainActivity.

Comment: Didn't work...The solution seems logical, but still produces the same errors.
Tried changing the following as well:

mMediaStoreAdapter = new MediaStoreAdapter(this.getActivity());
to
mMediaStoreAdapter = new MediaStoreAdapter(this.getContext());

In the MyPostsScreen Class.

Comment: @fadysi92 See if the updated answer resolve your issue.

Comment: YES! this worked, thank you so much!
Quick question though, how come we still use this.getActivity() and not this.getContext() in the MediaStoreAdapter?

Comment: Good question! Here is a good explanation on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32227421/2709580. For your scenario, it should be fine no matter which method you opt for.