# What is the difference between context and activity inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I’am inside a fragment what is the difference between `this.context` and `this.activity`
Eg:

```
val intent = Intent(this.activity!! , Activity::class.java)

val intent = Intent(this.context!! , Activity::class.java)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Activity and Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518206/what-is-the-difference-between-activity-and-context)

Comment: This is probably the answer you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227146/what-is-different-between-getcontext-and-getactivity-from-fragment-in-support-li/32227256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with context  > intent exists as long as application exists

with activity > intent exists as long as the activity exists

now you know what you need most of the cases.. :-D

Comment: Yep, this is great  answer

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh don't forget to upvote bro... :-)

Comment: yep, i will do it

Comment: I don't think `getContext` in a Fragment would ever return the Application. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227146/what-is-different-between-getcontext-and-getactivity-from-fragment-in-support-li/32227256

Answer (score 1):

Context is a Superclass of Activity.